# Chrome extension unable to occupy the full window width

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I developed a chrome extension in the format of a horizontal bar standing at the top of the user window. It's something "like" it:

[image]

But it is how it looks like when I add it to Chrome as an extension (see the icon at the top-right):

[image]

What is wrong here?

Here's the manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "CLAWS",
  "description": "testing",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://google.com.br/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icone_app.png",
    "default_popup": "HTML.html"
  }
}
```

EDIT: The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='CSS.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<div id="barra"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and CSS.css:

```
#barra{
   background-color:red;
   width:100%;
   height:80px;
}
```

Comment: Please post `HTML.html`.  It creates its own window, which is sized separately from the main window.  In particular, there's nothing that makes it have any particular width, so my guess is it defaults to a minimal width.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "to have a particular width"? It's about the extension window? And the code is at the post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popup window is it’s own window.  So when `#barra` specifies its width as 100%, it’s 100% of the popup window’s body element.  But nothing makes the body take a particular size.  For example, if I inspect your extension’s popup, Chrome tells me that the body element has a width of 9px, and margins of 8px on each side (set by the user agent style sheet).  Your values may differ, but they won’t be much larger.  If you want it to be wider, you’ll need to have CSS.css explicitly tell body how wide it should be, and not use percentages.

But if you want a bar at the top of the user window, I’m not sure if a browser action is what you want.  Browser actions close when they loose focus, in particular, when the user has any interaction with the webpage.  Instead, I think you would want a content script that would put the bar at the top of the screen (possibly just some css: `body{border-top:80px solid red;}`).

Comment: Thanks for answering! Really browser action is not what I desire here. But I don't think content scripts are appropiated, since I don't see such a complex interaction with the page the user are visiting (I may be wrong). And only use CSS to add the bar does not work also...

Comment: A content script is the only option for interacting with the page the user is visiting.  But it doesn't have to be all that complicated.  It's just the script or css you would execute or use to get the effect you wanted.  In this case, a line of css or a few lines of js should be able to get the job done.  Although that would also depend on what you want to do with the red bar at the top.

Comment: Well, I basically want the bar to stay everytime at the top of the user's windows and be able to identify words that him/her selects through a javascript at the own bar code. I'm totally newbie at extensions, but if the bar has a more complicated HTML (one that cannot be "simulated" with CSS), how should I do it with content scripts (that,as far as I know, only accept JS and CSS codes)?

Comment: Are you wanting some html in that bar?  If so, you'll need to use the js in a content script to create the appropriate html.

Comment: Got that...but I don't know exactly how to do it. I' ve tried to put my HTML inside "document.write()" calls and  even  use "createElement()/appendChild()/etc" when trying to mimic my HTML with JS, but had no positive results at all. If you still have patience to help me  (thanks!), I'll make a more specific question about that, if you prefer to answers there...

Comment: A new question would probably be the way to go, since the original one here has been answered (even if it wasn't answered the way you were hoping).  `createElement()/appendChild()` is preferable to `document.write()` for performance reasons.  You may also want to link to the new question from this one.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I Prefer to link it at the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531579/how-to-make-a-static-html-as-a-chrome-extension