# How to make a static HTML as a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to make a Chrome extension basically constituted as a HTML bar staying at the top of the user window all the time (after he activates it). The bar position would be something "like" it:

[image]

My question is: how can I achieve this behavior? I thinked about adding it as "browser action"at the manifest, but it does not fits since it disappears when loses focus. I also tried to add it as a `content script`, "embracing" my HTML with simple JS command `document.write(HTML line)`, but I can see no bar at all when I try it. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I think content_scripts is the way to go here. So you actually modify DOM of the page to display your content. You can look in other similar extensions.

For example: [StyleBot](https://github.com/ankit/stylebot/tree/master/stylebot). Here is how they [inject code to the page](https://github.com/ankit/stylebot/blob/master/stylebot/manifest.json#L79-L135):

```
"content_scripts": [{
...
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  ...
  "js": [
    ...
    "shared/modalbox/modalbox.js",
```

And here is code of [actual modal box](https://github.com/ankit/stylebot/blob/master/stylebot/shared/modalbox/modalbox.js#L14-L31).

```
this.box = $('<div>', {
    id: 'stylebot-modal'
}).append(html);

if (this.options.parent) {
    this.box.appendTo(this.options.parent);
}
else {
    this.box.appendTo(document.body);
}

this.box.css({
    height: this.options.height + '!important',
    width: this.options.width + ' !important',
    top: this.options.top + ' !important',
    left: this.options.left + ' !important'
});
```

Comment: Thanks" But could you please explain how it would fit in my case? I can't use "appendTo" to an element I've created...

Comment: Why can't you use appendTo?

Comment: Ok, now I saw I can create elements with JQuery. But, anyway, it is almost working, but it's not appearing in every site (in fact it's just working in Google...)